# agGrid Excel Export, Automatic Activation of Excel Filters after Export from ag-Grid

Tags: filter, export-to-excel, ag-grid-angular

I would like the Excel filters to be automatically activated after the export. Currently, I have to manually activate the filters using the "Apply Filter" button in Excel.Is there a way to configure this during the export from ag-Grid so that the Excel filters are automatically turned on? What settings or steps are required for this?Thank you for your assistance!

I don't want to use custom template